# NPN BJT Transistor Circuit Analysis Problem: Is This Question Solvable?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, npn

I've been doing some circuit analysis questions as practice but came across one that seemed very odd:

[image: Problem]

As far as I can tell, this question is missing information and therefore unsolvable? I was able to find I<sub>load</sub> since I had all the information needed there. However, I am unable to find R<sub>B</sub> simply because I'm missing V (voltage for the base). As there are two unknowns there, the problem cannot be solved. Am I correct in this judgement, or am I not seeing something?

Thanks.

Comment: You **are** given Vbe.

Comment: It is possible that the problem allows you to choose both \$V\$ and \$R_\text{B}\$? (I think their value for \$V_\text{BE}\$ is really the value for \$V_{\text{BE}_\text{SAT}}\$. So you know the base voltage (relative to ground), by definition.) \$\beta_\text{SAT}\$ isn't specified. But you may be allowed a reasonable guess for that, as well. But who knows?

Comment: i don't think there is enough information.  and \$V_{BE} = 0.95\$ V seems awful high.

Comment: The voltage measurements indicate the Collector voltage is well below the Base voltage, thus the transistor is operating in Saturation. You know the Base voltage, so derive a formula that depends on the unknown Vin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t come up with a numerical answer, however you can come up with an expression for Rb using the unknown voltage V and the forced beta (often Ic/Ib = 10), since you can easily calculate the collector current.